# How to copy a folder with all the subfolders from colab to drive?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

I need to copy a folder I created in the temporary space of Google Colab to Drive.

This is the command

```
%cp Thesis2023 /drive/MyDrive/Thesis2023
```

Thesis 2023 is the folder I need to copy to drive, but I get this error

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'Thesis2023'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to copy all files from the folder to the new folder created in the destination, you need to use the -r command (-r stands for recursive):

```
cp -r Thesis2023 /drive/MyDrive/Thesis2023
```

This code should copy the folder and everything inside to the new directory, in this case your Google drive.

I see that the question tag is python: If you are trying to use this command in a Python program, you can `import subprocess` and use the `subprocess.run` command to run the cp command:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cp', '-r', 'Thesis2023', '/drive/MyDrive/Thesis2023'])
```